# Fabric over reverse SSH tunnel

Tags: ssh, fabric, tunnel

Is there a trick to running Fabric over a reverse SSH tunnel? An interactive `ssh` connects fine back over the turnnel, but running `fab`, I just get asked for my password repeatedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a snippet with a solution

https://gist.github.com/856179

Just copy, paste and use

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that doesn't involve writing any extra Python code:

If you set up your SSH configuration to tunnel over a SOCKS proxy, you can tell Fabric to use the SSH configuration. It's sweet.

Example `$HOME/.ssh/config file`:

```
Host bastion
HostName bastion.yourdomain.com
DynamicForward 0.0.0.0:1080
ServerAliveInterval 120
ServerAliveCountMax 30

Host hostbehindthebastion.yourdomain.com
ProxyCommand /usr/bin/nc -x 127.0.0.1:1080 %h %p
```

Now tell Fabric to use the configuration:

```
env.use_ssh_config = True
env.hosts = [
    "user@hostbehindthebastion.yourdomain.com",
]
```

Now `ssh bastion` in one window, then run `fab` from another window.

See the [official Fabric documentation](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.6/usage/execution.html#leveraging-native-ssh-config-files) for more information.

NB. You will have to have nc (netcat) installed on your machine to use this solution.