# ssh python fabric

Tags: python, ssh, deployment, fabric

I don't actually understand how to do that.
I have access to local computer for example 192.168.1.101 with some_user. From that computer i have access to another comp (via vpn) 10.0.132.17 and only from here i can reach access to computer 10.0.132.15 where i need to deploy my script.

so I need to:

```
$ ssh some_user@192.168.1.101 -> ssh another_user@10.0.132.17 -> ssh another_user@10.0.132.15
```

may i somehow do: `ssh some_user@192.168.1.101 -p 2222` and get access to `another_user@10.0.132.15`?

or in python fabric to write somehow env variable?

Comment: Run th script from the the VPN?

Comment: Nope, the script is python fabric script. and running it from my local comp. 192.168.1.102

Comment: OKay. What you need is SSH tunnel. Try this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237893/fabric-over-reverse-ssh-tunnel

Answer (score 0):

Another option than using an explicit tunnel is to set up ssh to transparently forward through your proxies. Put in your `~/.ssh/config` something like the following:

```
Host proxy_midstage
    User another_user
    HostName 10.0.132.17
    ProxyCommand ssh -q some_user@192.168.1.101 nc %h %p

Host proxy_final
    User another_user
    HostName 10.0.132.15
    ProxyCommand ssh -q proxy_midstage nc %h %p
```

Then the command `ssh proxy_final` will jump you straight to the deployment server. Presumably fabric can use that, though I'm not positive.